# How to set up Jekyll cleanly on an existing OSX system?

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll

I am an inexperienced Ruby user and I want to start using a Jekyll theme. I am working on OSX El Capitan and there may be old Ruby tools lying around on this machine.

I have downloaded [this theme](http://richbray.me/frap/) and installed it to a local directory. Next I tried to run `bundle` and saw this error:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.5.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Full error output here: http://pastebin.com/mv2r91xU

Next, I tried running `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.9'`, but I saw this error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/gem: No such file or directory
```

I don't know how to install `gem`, and I suspect I'm not using the "right" Ruby or bundler. Where should these tools be? What do I need to check I've deleted to start cleanly from scratch? (e.g. I tried setting up rbenv, but I think it may have failed because I already had RVM installed)

These are the paths to ruby and bundler:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ which bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

Comment: It'd be `bundle install ...`, not `gem install`. That said, I'd strongly consider using a Ruby version manager (e.g., rbenv, rvm) to control which Ruby you're running, and a project's specific gem dependencies, to avoid conflicting w/ OS X's old-ish default Ruby installs.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to manage your Ruby versions, and ignoring the default system-wide version. You mention you tried, but I think it'd be worth giving it another go.

rbenv is best installed through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), install it with the following:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then install rbenv with Homebrew:

```
$ brew install rbenv ruby-build
```

You can then set and switch between Ruby versions (giving you clean environments) anytime without changing the default system version:

```
$ rbenv install 2.3.1
$ rbenv global 2.3.1
$ ruby -v
```

Once Ruby is sorted, you should be able to install and run the latest Jekyll through the Bundler:

```
$ gem install jekyll
$ jekyll new my-awesome-site
$ cd my-awesome-site
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Running Jekyll through Bundler rather than directly is the new suggested method.